# Node package.json `exports` field not aliasing `require()` calls

Tags: node.js, package.json, es6-modules

I am trying to use the `exports` option in `package.json` in order to allow both CJS and ESM entrypoints.

Here, I have a simple package with the following file structure.

```
package/
  src/
    index.js
    main.cjs
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
```

The file contents are as follows:

```js
// package/src/index.js
console.log('index.js')
```

```js
// package/src/main.cjs
console.log('main.cjs')
```

```json
// package/package.json
{
    "name": "package",
    "type": "module",
    "main": "./src/main.cjs",
    "module": "./src/index.js",
    "exports": {
      ".": {
        "import": "./src/index.js",
        "require": "./src/main.cjs"
      },
      "./index.js": {
        "import": "./src/index.js",
        "require": "./src/main.cjs"
      },
      "./src/index.js": {
        "import": "./src/index.js",
        "require": "./src/main.cjs"
      }
    }
}
```

```json
// package/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext"
  }
}
```

Now, separately, I have an external package that is using the first package.

```
external/
  test.cjs
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
```

The files are

```js
// external/test.cjs
require("../package/src/index.js")
```

```json
// external/package.json
{
    "name": "external",
    "type": "module",
    "main": "./test.cjs"
}
```

```json
// external/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext"
  }
}
```

When I run `node external/test.cjs`, I get an `ERR_REQUIRE_ESM` error.

```
/external/test.cjs:1
require("../package/src/index.js")
^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /package/src/index.js from /external/test.cjs not supported.
index.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in /package/package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).

    at Object.<anonymous> (/external/test.cjs:1:1) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

Here is my confusion: I thought that the `exports` field is supposed to create an alias for importing and requiring the package. Thus, I expect that when I can `require("../package/src/index.js")`, that the export would be aliased to `./src/main.cjs`. But clearly, this is not the case. What am I misunderstanding?

Notes:

- I tried changing the `tsconfig.json` files to `jsconfig.json`
- I tried using the `imports` package.json option as well
- I tried setting the `engines` package.json option to node14+
- I am running it with `Node.js v18.6.0`

Answer (score 0):

When requiring files by relative path, only "type" field from the `package.json` is considered, "exports" are ignored. Quoting relevant steps from the [cjs module resolution](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#all-together):

```
require(X) from module at path Y
3. If X begins with './' or '/' or '../'  
   a. LOAD_AS_FILE(Y + X)  ## but when X starts with /, Y is ignored

LOAD_AS_FILE(X)
1. If X is a file, load X as its file extension format. STOP
```

File extension format is esm because there's `"type": "module"` in the `package.json` in the folder above.

"exports" come into effect when a module is required "as a package" or "as a directory", that is

```js
require('package/index.js') // when it's installed as a dependency in node_modules

require('../package') // when package is a directory with a "package.json", 
                        // will look for "." in "exports" there
```